# JasperReports long field's border

Tags: jasper-reports

I've got a long text field which wraps to another page, the problem is that the border on first page does not matches end of page...

I guess I coul've fixed it by adding some Frame element, but I couldn't achive it by now.

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the cause of this problem was  "Strech type: relative to tallest object"

my solution was to put all the fields in an outlined frame
and disable fields bottom border